# Transferring Object with MapStruct via 2 Mappers using Generated Class

Tags: java, oop, object, mapstruct, mapper

- I have 3 Classes: A, B, C.
- Each of them has single ObjectX field.
- Classes A and C have also ObjectY field.
- Class B is auto-generated, I can't modify it.
- I have mapper from A to B, and mapper from B to C, they don't
  include ObjectY (it is ignored).

Is it possible somehow to modify these mappers in order to include ObjectY (without adding mapping between A to C)?

mapper code is below:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
@Mapping(target = "ObjectX")
  B AtoB(A a);

@Mapping(target = "ObjectX")
  C BtoC(B b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to translate `A` to `B` and then `B` to `C` and you also want to keep `ObjectY` field.
The problem is that `B` don't have the `ObjectY` field, so it cannot store the value of it through this translation.

Only solution which comes to my mind is to create class `MyB` which extends class `B` and contains `ObjectY` field and then change your mapper like this:

```
public class MyB extends B {
    private ObjectY objectY;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    MyB AtoB(A a);

    C BtoC(MyB b);
}
```

But I'm not sure if it is possible in your use case.